# Rotate Texture2D from XRCpuImage and transfer it to RawImage - Crashes after approx. 30 seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, augmented-reality, texture2d

I get the last image via XRCpuImage convert it to a Texture2D and transfer it to a RawImage.
The Result looks like this: [XRCpuImage on RawImage - no rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNqe0.jpg)

As you can see, the transferred texture is rotated, so I use a function called "rotateTexture" to rotate the texture to the correct position:[Rotated Texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yenzB.jpg)

The rotation looks good so far, but when I run the application it crashes after about 30 seconds.

Could someone tell me what could be wrong with the code below:

```
using System;
using Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;
using Unity.Collections;

public class CPU_RawImage : MonoBehaviour
{
    Texture2D m_CameraTexture;
    GameObject DR_layer;
       

    [SerializeField]
    [Tooltip("The ARCameraManager which will produce frame events.")]
    ARCameraManager m_CameraManager;  //Anlegen m_CameraManger
    

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or set the <c>ARCameraManager</c>.
    /// </summary>
    public ARCameraManager cameraManager
    {
        get => m_CameraManager;
        set => m_CameraManager = value;  //Besetzen mit ARCamera
    }

    [SerializeField]
    RawImage m_RawCameraImage;

    /// <summary>
    /// The UI RawImage used to display the image on screen.
    /// </summary>
    public RawImage rawCameraImage
    {
        get => m_RawCameraImage;
        set => m_RawCameraImage = value;
    }

    
    XRCpuImage.Transformation m_Transformation = XRCpuImage.Transformation.MirrorX;
    

    void OnEnable()
    {
        if (m_CameraManager != null)
        {
            m_CameraManager.frameReceived += OnCameraFrameReceived;
        }
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        if (m_CameraManager != null)
        {
            m_CameraManager.frameReceived -= OnCameraFrameReceived;
        }
    }

    //Rotate Funktion
    private Texture2D rotateTexture(Texture2D originalTexture, bool clockwise)
         {
             Color32[] original = originalTexture.GetPixels32();
             Color32[] rotated = new Color32[original.Length];
             int w = originalTexture.width;
             int h = originalTexture.height;
     
             int iRotated, iOriginal;
     
             for (int j = 0; j < h; ++j)
             {
                 for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i)
                 { 
                     iRotated = (i + 1) * h - j - 1;
                     iOriginal = clockwise ? original.Length - 1 - (j * w + i) : j * w + i;
                     rotated[iRotated] = original[iOriginal];          

                 }
             }
     
             Texture2D rotatedTexture = new Texture2D(h, w);
             rotatedTexture.SetPixels32(rotated); 
             rotatedTexture.Apply();
             return rotatedTexture;
         }

        

    unsafe void UpdateCameraImage(int[] pixel)
    {
        // Attempt to get the latest camera image. If this method succeeds,
        // it acquires a native resource that must be disposed (see below).
        if (!cameraManager.TryAcquireLatestCpuImage(out XRCpuImage image))  
        {
            return;
        }

        // Once we have a valid XRCpuImage, we can access the individual image "planes"
        // (the separate channels in the image). XRCpuImage.GetPlane provides
        // low-overhead access to this data. This could then be passed to a
        // computer vision algorithm. Here, we will convert the camera image
        // to an RGBA texture and draw it on the screen.

        // Choose an RGBA format.
        // See XRCpuImage.FormatSupported for a complete list of supported formats.
        var format = TextureFormat.RGBA32;

        if (m_CameraTexture == null || m_CameraTexture.width != image.width || m_CameraTexture.height != image.height)
        {
            m_CameraTexture = new Texture2D(image.width, image.height, format, false);
        }

        
        // Convert the image to format, flipping the image across the Y axis.
        // We can also get a sub rectangle, but we'll get the full image here.
        var conversionParams = new XRCpuImage.ConversionParams(image, format, m_Transformation);

        // Texture2D allows us write directly to the raw texture data
        // This allows us to do the conversion in-place without making any copies.
        var rawTextureData = m_CameraTexture.GetRawTextureData<byte>();
        try
        {
            image.Convert(conversionParams, new IntPtr(rawTextureData.GetUnsafePtr()), rawTextureData.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            // We must dispose of the XRCpuImage after we're finished
            // with it to avoid leaking native resources.
            image.Dispose();
        }

        // Apply the updated texture data to our texture
        m_CameraTexture.Apply();

        //rotate Texture clockwise
        //m_CameraTexture = rotateTexture(m_CameraTexture, true);

        // Set the RawImage's texture so we can visualize it.
        m_RawCameraImage.texture = m_CameraTexture;   
    }     

    void Start(){
        DR_layer = GameObject.Find("RawImage");
    }

    void OnCameraFrameReceived(ARCameraFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        int[] pixel = {200,1000};
        UpdateCameraImage(pixel);
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `RotateImage(texture, 90f);`

```
    public static void RotateImage(Texture2D tex, float angleDegrees)
    {
        int width = tex.width;
        int height = tex.height;
        float halfHeight = height * 0.5f;
        float halfWidth = width * 0.5f;

        var texels = tex.GetRawTextureData<Color32>();
        var copy = System.Buffers.ArrayPool<Color32>.Shared.Rent(texels.Length);
        Unity.Collections.NativeArray<Color32>.Copy(texels, copy, texels.Length);

        float phi = Mathf.Deg2Rad * angleDegrees;
        float cosPhi = Mathf.Cos(phi);
        float sinPhi = Mathf.Sin(phi);

        int address = 0;
        for (int newY = 0; newY < height; newY++)
        {
            for (int newX = 0; newX < width; newX++)
            {
                float cX = newX - halfWidth;
                float cY = newY - halfHeight;
                int oldX = Mathf.RoundToInt(cosPhi * cX + sinPhi * cY + halfWidth);
                int oldY = Mathf.RoundToInt(-sinPhi * cX + cosPhi * cY + halfHeight);
                bool InsideImageBounds = (oldX > -1) & (oldX < width)
                                       & (oldY > -1) & (oldY < height);

                texels[address++] = InsideImageBounds ? copy[oldY * width + oldX] : default;
            }
        }

        // No need to reinitialize or SetPixels - data is already in-place.
        tex.Apply(true);

        System.Buffers.ArrayPool<Color32>.Shared.Return(copy);
    }
```